# Is $|1-i|$ larger than $|1|$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am confused about complex numbers. Does $1-i$ lie outside the unit circle? How do I show that the absolute value of $1-i$ is larger than that of $1$?

Comment: The question in the title made *no sense*, but the body of the post contained a different question which made sense. I've edited the title.

Comment: `|a| = sqrt(C² + R²)` => `|1 - i| = sqrt(1² + 1²) = sqrt(2)` and `|1| = 1`. `sqrt(2) > 1 => |1 - i| > |1|`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Let me do something *very* different for me. Let me give a geometric proof:

Note that $1-i$ is the bottom-right corner of the square whose center is $0$ and whose edges have length $2$. The other corners are $1+i; -1+i; -1-i$.

The diagonal running from $-1+i$ to $1-i$ is a straight line passing through $0$. Its length, by the Pythagoras theorem, is $2\sqrt2=\sqrt8$. Therefore the distance between $0$ and each of the corners is exactly half, i.e. $\sqrt2$.

And it is trivial to see that $\sqrt2>1$.

Here is a drawing:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image: complex plane]

Comment: I must be very tired if I am thinking about this in terms of geometry.

Comment: ...and now I added a drawing. The horror... (If anyone can improve this drawing somehow, please do. :-))

Comment: Do you mean running from $- 1 + i$ to $1 - i$?

Comment: @Andrew, that is what I mean.

Comment: This is really the best demonstration of this property. +1

Comment: +1 for being the only reasonable (read: geometric) answer!

Comment: I concur, given the lack in intuitive understanding of complex numbers the OP showed, this really is the only reasonable answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : stop apologizing... Its a fantastic answer!

Comment: @Peter: Awesomse!!

Comment: @Harsh: Thanks, but I wouldn't normally have given such answer. Not geometric and not one illustrated.

Comment: I only saw this answer now. How... atypical. ;)

Comment: @Ｊ.M.: Why, yes!

Comment: @AsafKaragila How did you draw the picture?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: I used GIMP, and the basic geometric shapes. If you look at the history, though, you'll see that I didn't draw *this* image, but a much uglier one. This one was contributed by someone else with a bit more design skills than me.

Comment: My dear Asaf: May I ask you to take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2914783/8581)? That is mine. Is that a wrong version? Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, th OP didn't have any attentions to it.

Answer (score 45):

By definition, the absolute value of a given complex number $z$ with $z=x+iy$ (for some $x,y\in \Bbb R$) is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and it is denoted by $|z|$.

If $z=1-i$, according to the definition we get $|1-i|=\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt {2}>1=|1|$.

Comment: Is this a violation of 7. from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024302/631742) ? 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes. I evolved :) This is from 2013. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 33):

**Hint:** By definition, if $a+bi$ is a complex number ($a$ and $b$ being real numbers, as usual),
$$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

---

Also, it is really incorrect to say that "$1-i$ is larger than $1$"; the complex numbers have no ordering. You should just instead say that $|1-i|>1$.

Answer (score 15):

In complex number, you have to compute the module of a number to say if it is "larger" than something. In general the module is $$|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

In your case 
$$|1-i|=\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$

Then 
$$\sqrt{2}\geq|1|$$

And this imply that $1-i$ lies outside of the unit circle

Answer (score 10):

One of the properties of complex numbers is that we cannot compare them, but we can compare their modulus.

you can compare $|1-i|$ with $|1|$, equivalent with $\sqrt{1^{2}+1^{2}}\geq 1.$

Answer (score 5):

$|1|= 1$

$|1-i|= \sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$

Since the modulus is radius in the Argand plane,

$|1-i|>|1|$

Answer (score 4):

Well as far as the title is concerned,

$|1-i|=\sqrt2$>$|1|$=1

$|1-i|$>$|1|$

Answer (score 3):

This is a small variant of Asaf Karagila's geometric proof:  If $a$ and $b$ are two points in the complex plane, the distance between them is $|a-b|$, so if you draw the (right isosceles) triangle with $a=1$, $b=i$ and $c=0$, you see that $|1-i|\gt1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another different approach:

The **unique** angle (in $[0,2\pi)$) between the vector $(1,i)$ in the complex plane and the x-axis is $\phi=\frac{7\pi}{4}$

Euler's identity yields now:

$$1-i=L(e^{\frac{7\pi}{4}i})=L\left(\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{4}\right)\right)=L\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=L\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=L\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) $$

Hence $L=\sqrt{2}$